# Lumia 920 Pricing

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-920

I know this is a pretty basic question, but I feel like this a good forum to ask it upon.

I haven't heard anything on the pricing of the Nokia Lumia 920.

I'm an avid iPhone user and as long as the pricing for this phone is less, I can't wait it buy it.

Any ideas, on an exact or estimated pricing? Contract or no-term?

Comment: This question is too localised and you should now be able to get the answer direct from your local retailer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that's been officially released from Nokia is that pricing would be "competitive" with other high end smart phones.  This would suggest pricing around the $200 point as this is the typical starting price of the majority of new flagship phones like the iPhone, HTC One X, and Galaxy S III.  I know Nokia was aggressive with their pricing on the original Lumia so it's possible to be cheaper but like I said, nothing official yet beyond being competitive.

Comment: Are you referring to $200 when included in a 3 year deal?

Comment: Not sure about other parts of the world but that's usually the price with a new 2 year agreement in the US.